# Error: Argument of type '{ field1: Date; field2: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMyInterfaceState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0, react-tsx

My *interfaces* *(.tsx)* are given below:

```
export interface IMyInterfaceProps{
}

export interface IMyInterfaceState{
    fields: {
        ID:string,
        Name:string,
        field1: Date,
        field2: Date,
        date: Date
    },
    errors: {
        Name: string,
      }
}
```

My *Class* *(.tsx)* is:

```
class MyClass extends Component<IMyInterfaceProps, IMyInterfaceState>{
   form:any;
   constructor(props:any){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      fields: {
        ID:'',
        Name:'',
        field1: new Date(),
        field2: new Date(),
        date: new Date()
      },
      errors: {
          Name: '',
      }
    };
   }

   change = (e:any) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value} as Pick<IMyInterfaceProps, keyof IMyInterfaceState>);
   };

   handleChange = (date: Date) => {
      this.setState({
         field1: date,  //Here I'm getting this error
         field2: date
      });
    };

  render(){
      <div>
             <DatePicker id='field1' className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}
                     placeholderText="Select a date" ></DatePicker>
       </div>
  }
}
```

My dependencies from *package.json* are:

```
{
  "name": "react-ds-poc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.14.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-form-input-validation": "^2.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

I tried couple of solutions available for this problem [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729742/react-typescript-argument-of-type-x-number-any-is-not-assignable-to#) and I could solve it for my *change* event but for the *handleChange* event I get the following error:

> Argument of type '{ field1: Date; field2: Date; }' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'IMyInterfaceState | ((prevState:
>   Readonly, props: Readonly) =>
>   IMyInterfaceState | ... 1 more ... | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'field1' does
>   not exist in type 'IMyInterfaceState | ((prevState:
>   Readonly, props: Readonly) =>
>   IMyInterfaceState | ... 1 more ... | null) | Pick<...>'.

Please help me get rid of from this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently replacing your entire state object with the contents of only your `fields` property. You need to set state with an object that fulfills the contract of `IMyInterfaceState`. Not totally certain, but you might be able to get away with

```
this.setState({
  fields: {
    field1: date,
    field2: date
  }
});
```

but you may have to define `ID`, `Name`, `date` and perhaps `errors.Name`, too.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped, how you're right I've to include all the properties present in field.

Comment: Sweet! If you can tag my answer as accepted, that will make me and future answerers happy. :-)

Comment: That compile time error has gone, however I'm getting so many other errors when I select the date via DatePicker.

Comment: I'm looking in to those errors, will accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: Oh dear. The joys of programming!